# How can I access private members from other classes?

Tags: c#, field, private

I'm not that new to C# but don't have as much experience as in Java.
As you know, in Java, we can access all the private members from outer classes.
So I tried the same thing in C# because I had some fields and methods needed to be accessed from only inside my plugin library and didn't want it to be shown to users. A simple example can be like this.

```
public static class StaticClass {

    public class InstanceClass {
        private int oldValue;
        public int Value;
    }

    public static void Backup(InstanceClass ic) {
        ic.oldValue = ic.Value;
    }

    public static void Restore(InstanceClass ic) {
        ic.Value    = ic.oldValue;
    }
}
```

If I make the field oldValue public, then it'll be mess and look dirty when end users use the plugin. It doesn't have to be an Inner class or in a some specific form. I just want to know if there is any way to control or access private members of an instance from other static classes in the same assembly only by me.

Comment: Just wondering: everything is static in there, but your InstanceClass is not? If C# is like Java, then how should some static context have access to non-static internals?

Comment: Your answer is here [C# Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Comment: You need to use ´internal´ as access modifier. Then the class can only be accessed from classes that are inside your assembly.

Comment: @GhostCat As for nested classes in C#, it's more like C++ but not Java. Java doesn't have static outer class, right?

Comment: Thanks to all of you who wrote an answer or a comment here. I'm so ashamed now.. It was a very basic and stupid question. Big thanks for the reminder. And to those of you who think this coding style is not that good, I know, but I had to know. I would say, it's kind of like Reflection in my opinion. Reflection is slow and bad in many cases but sometimes it's really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For allowing access only within assembly use `internal` modifier.

```
public class InstanceClass {
        internal int oldValue;
        public int Value;
    }
```

Comment: The OP wants access from the containing class, not the whole assembly.

Comment: In OP's last line access is needed for the whole assembly `access private members of an instance from other static classes in the same assembly only by me`.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, you're right, my initial try was as you said and still curious how to do it, but this will do enough for now.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in C#. The container class has no special access over the nested class.

You can access private members of the container from the nested class, but not vice versa. The pattern you're trying to use simply isn't used in C# - it's a violation of member accessibility. There are some hacks to force the Java pattern on C# (using reflection or abusing interfaces), but they are just that - hacks.

The "cleanest" approach might look something like this:

```
public static class StaticClass 
{
  private interface IInstanceClassInternal
  {
    int OldValue { get; set; }
  }

  public sealed class InstanceClass : IInstanceClassInternal 
  {
    int IInstanceClassInternal.OldValue { get; set; }

    public int Value;
  }

  public static void Backup(InstanceClass ic)
  {
    ((IInstanceClassInternal)ic).OldValue = ic.Value;
  }

  public static void Restore(InstanceClass ic) 
  {
    ic.Value = ((IInstanceClassInternal)ic).OldValue;
  }
}
```

It's obvious that you're trying to write Java in C# - the patterns, the coding style... That's probably a bad idea. Those static methods should probably be extension methods. The "hidden functionality in an object" doesn't quite sit with C#'s notion of OOP - your parent shouldn't have free access to your guts, it should only really have the same public interface everyone else has. After all, that's the whole point of LSP - such tight coupling is quite tricky for any extensibility. Why separate `StaticClass` from `InstanceClass` in the first place, if you want `StaticClass` to mess with `InstanceClass`es privates? Just make `Backup` and `Restore` public members of `InstanceClass` - or even a part of an interface (perhaps even through explicit implementation, if you want to "hide" it from users of `InstanceClass`).

Comment: You are right and agree about the coding style, but sometimes I really want to do it. Let's say, you provide a data class or struct to users which can be written by users. And then users need to put the instance to a certain static method for some action. The method will call some private methods including Backup() and Restore() which will never be directly called by users. Private members needed to be sit in an instance and a library's access to those.. what do you think? I meant, a data class(or struct) which will be saved to disk for later use.

Comment: @Jenix Well, I don't like that idea much. It goes quite a bit against the better parts of OOP - all that's left if you don't follow this is superficial stuff like code reuse through inheritance. You're throwing away polymorphism (closely related to substitution), isolation, encapsulation... Maybe it's okay to do that for infrastructural stuff. But it still means you lose those accessibility points - kind of like including assembly code in a C project means you lose portability. I've come to favour cleaner responsibilities for object, more explicit interfaces, composition. But that's just me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `internal` access modifier, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Internal is only visible from inside the assembly

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FNavfE

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make it "internal"? It will be available in same dll but not external dll.

```
public class InstanceClass {
    internal int oldValue;
    public int Value;
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40357305/814206; the other answer probably didn't exist when Fabio Silva Lima started typing, Akshey Bhat pressed the submit button just 3 minutes before.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can use *Reflection* (if you insist on `private` field and a static class methods):

```
using System.Reflection;

... 

public static void Backup(InstanceClass ic) {
  if (null == ic)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("ic");

  ic.GetType()
    .GetField("oldValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .SetValue(ic, ic.Value);
}

public static void Restore(InstanceClass ic) {
  if (null == ic)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("ic");

  ic.Value = (int) (ic.GetType()
    .GetField("oldValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(ic));
}
```

however, a much better approach is to change access modifier from `private` to `internal`:

```
public class InstanceClass {
    internal int oldValue;
    public int Value;
}
```

Even *better* solution is to move both `Backup` and `Restore` methods into `InstanceClass`:

```
public class InstanceClass {
    private int oldValue;
    public int Value;

    public void Backup() {
      oldValue = Value; 
    }

    public void Restore() {
      Value = oldValue; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for another suggestion! I never thought of using Reflection. I'll try this too

Answer (score 0):

This field `oldValue` is an implementation detail of both `StaticClass` and `InstanceClass`.  Lets make `InstanceClass` an implementation detail of `StaticClass` and export an interface `StaticClass.IInstance` to external clients:

```
public static class StaticClass {
     public interface IInstance {
         int Value { get; set; }
     }

     private class InstanceClass: IInstance {
         public int oldValue;
         public Value { get; set; }
     }

     // Static class becomes responsible for handing out `IInstance` objects
     public static IInstance GetInstance() {
         return new InstanceClass();
     }

     public static void Backup(IInstance i) {
         if (i is InstanceClass ic) {
             ic.oldValue = ic.Value;
         }
         else {
             throw new InvallidOperationException("Can only Backup IInstance objects that were created by GetInstance");
         }
     }

     public static void Restore(IInstance i) {
         if (I is InstanceClass ic)
         {
             ic.Value = ic.oldValue;
         }
         else {
             throw new InvallidOperationException("Can only Restore IInstance objects that were created by GetInstance");
         }
     }
```

This solution is similar to the one [Luaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan) [proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40357383/814206).  But instead of using an interface to export private data, it uses an interface to limit the publicly available data; to my opinion this is a cleaner design with less surprises.
It does change `Value` from a field to a property; so when you really need a field, this pattern does not work.

The static class in the example of OP makes it a bit awkward and having better solutions, but imagine this in a regular class, perhaps in a repository.  Working on a repository, where observers should be notified when properties of items in the repository are set and not wanting the items to contain a reference to the repository or to the repositories observers, led me to searching for ["method only accessible to container class?"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20method%20only%20accessible%20to%20container%20class) which led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40357278/814206).

I intend to solve it as follows:

```
public class Repo
{
    public interface IItem
    {
        int Id { get; }
        string MyProperty { get; }
    }

    private class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public string MyProperty { get; private set; }

        public bool TrySetMyProperty(string newValue)
        {
            if (!Equals(MyProperty, newValue) &&
                IsPreconditionValid())
            {
                MyProperty = newValue;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            IsPreconditionValid() => true;
        }
    }


    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnChanged;

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Item> items = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Item>();

    public IItem GetOrCreateItemById(int id)
    {
        bool changed = false;
        IItem result = items.GetOrAdd(int, CreateItem);
        if (changed)
        {
            OnChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        return result;

        IItem CreateItem(int key)
        {
            changed = true;
            return new Item() { Id = key };
        }
    }

    public bool TrySetItemMyProperty(int id, string newValue)
    {
        if (items.TryGet(id, out Item i))
        {
            if (i.TrySetMyProperty(newValue))
            {
                OnChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```